# Как правильно переносить слова?

Tags: орфография, перенос

Какие существуют правила переносов слов и есть ли они вообще? Как неправильно переносить русские слова?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главное правило переноса слов в русском языке - это разделение их на слоги. Переносить можно строго по слогам. Если в середина слова присутствует удвоенная согласная, лучше перенести, разорвав две одинаковые согласные.
Пример: *груп-па, мировоз-зрение.*
Нельзя переносить на другую строчку одну букву, равно как и оставлять на строке одну букву. Также нельзя отделять согласную букву от последующей гласной.
Пример:
-неправильно: *вп-еремежку, подп-исан*;
-правильно: *впере-межку, под-писан*.
Красивее выглядят переносы, когда они находятся между приставкой и корнем.
Пример: *под-собка, при-каз.*

Answer (score 0):

Если опустить некоторые особые ситуации, то для современных правил переноса обязательны следующие требования:

Перенос осуществляется как правило по слогам. При этом:
~1. Одна буква на строке не остаётся и одна не переносится.
~2. На каждой строчке должна остаться хотя бы одна гласная буква.
~3. Согласная (включая Й) перед гласной переносится вместе с этой гласной. 
~4. Буквы Ъ и Ь от предшествующей согласной не отрываются.
~5. Й перед согласной не отрывается от предыдущей строки.
~6. Удвоенные согласные перед гласной рекомендуется разбивать при переносе, если за ними идет согласная. Но если за удвоенной согласной идет тоже согласная, то разрывать удвоенные согласные нельзя. 
~7. Перенос в месте дефиса разрешен, при этом дефис сохраняется, знак переноса опускается и на второй строке не дублируется.

В остальных случаях рекомендуется перенос согласно делению слова на морфы.

В основном - все. Остальные правила касаются переносов аббревиатур и других малоактуальных случаев.